# How to check if a page's content has been modified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1 - I have a web page, in that page there are many external links

2 - When user click on any external link then a popup should be come with the message that page has been modified by dynamic action or it not.

3 - How can I check the page status using JavaScript / jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go for "onhaschange" event of window/body on change simply set some flag which you can check on click of link to show whether page is changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Add some state variable to javascript, like:

```
wasModified = false;
```

Subscribe on click event of every external link or whatever you want to react on, like that:

```
$('.external-link-class-selector').click(function(){
    wasModified = true;
    //in case click mean it was modified and you should notify user
    alert('Page was modified');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

see

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "",
         type: "post",
         dataType: "" ,
         data: , 
        }).done(function() {
                //sucess
                            });
```

make a function in Javascript including above function and  Post values by this method to the same page and append success message on the page.

Comment: edit html include a div at the top by id of forexample 'message' then append the message in the .done(function() {
                //sucess message here
                            });